# Swagger not detecting Spring Data Rest APIs with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, spring-data-rest

I setup a Spring Boot project including Spring Data Rest and Swagger:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my Swagger configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Excerpt from application.properties:

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
server.context-path=/myapp
```

When I run the server, all rest endpoints are correctly mapped and reachable to `/myapp/api/...`, including a custom RestController I created on my own.

However:

- at `http://localhost:8080/myapp/api` I can see the list of Spring
  Data Rest APIs (in Json format) but cannot see my custom RestController endpoints.
- at `http://localhost:8080/myapp/swagger-ui.html` I see a nice gui which only lists my custom RestController and the error endpoint, not the Spring Data Rest APIs. In fact, http://localhost:8080/myapp/v2/api-docs does not make any reference to Spring Data Rest endpoints, but only to my custom RestController and to the error endpoint.

How can I fix my Spring Data Rest & Swagger configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Spring Data Rest support](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#support-for-spring-data-rest) was only introduced in springfox version 2.6.0. If you follow [the instructions](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#support-for-spring-data-rest) after upgrading to the latest version of springfox (2.6.1 at the time of this writing) you shouldn't have a problem with rendering the endpoints.

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded my version to 2.6.1 and added the Maven dependency, as of instructions, but I keep being in the same situation.

Comment: Add:  `.pathMapping("/myapp")` after `.build()`

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade to latest version of swagger

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Additionally import spring data rest annotation on spring Configuration/Application class.

```
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: `@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)` did the trick for me. I put it in the `Application` class. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Did you import the configuration from springfox-data-rest? As Dilip Krishnan said, I followed the instructions and imported the configuration, adding this annotation to my Main Application class:

```
@Import({springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.configuration.SpringDataRestConfiguration.class})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey, where is it supposed to be placed? What file?

Comment: @LuizMitidiero You can for example add it to main application class or on SwaggerConfig class.

Answer (score 2):

For spring boot 2 you need to use `springfox 3.0`. Unfortunately at the time of this writing this version is not released yet but you can use the snapshot version.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
      <name>jcenter</name>
      <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Also you need to replace `@EnableSwagger2` with `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc`.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.configuration.SpringDataRestConfiguration;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2WebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)

public class SwaggerConfig {
  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build();
  }
}
```