# Spring Data REST Endpoints Not Generating In Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, spring-data-rest, springfox

I've implemented a controller using `@BasePathAwareController` which also takes advantage of Spring Data REST (for finds to expose sort/size etc.) 
along with some custom endpoints (for updates etc.). The application is working as expected and the endpoints Spring 
Data REST generates are working as expected and I can see the self links appear in the responses, however, i can't see 
these endpoints in Swagger UI. I can just see my custom endpoints 
defined in my Controller.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425425/swagger-not-detecting-spring-data-rest-apis-with-spring-boot) I need to use Swagger `3.0.0-SNAPSHOT` with `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc`

Here's my configurations:

My `app.yml`:

```
spring:
    data:
      rest:
        basePath: /api/v1
```

My `POM` file:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<properties>        
        <springfox.swagger.version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</springfox.swagger.version>       
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.swagger.version}</version>         
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Swagger Config File:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(ServletContext servletContext) {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)          
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.package.name"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build().apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiEndPointsInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("My App REST API's")
            .description("My App REST API's")            
            .version("1.0").build();
    }

}
```

My repo:

```
  @RepositoryRestResource(exported=true, collectionResourceRel="group", path="group")
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Group> {


}
```

Why can't i see the default endpoints that Spring Data REST produces?

Comment: if you try : `@EnableSwagger2` rather than `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc` !

Comment: `@EnableSwagger2` is not available in version `3.0.0-SNAPSHOT `:-(

Comment: Try with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58026307/11269375

Comment: After rolling back the version of `springfox-swagger2` to `2.9.2` and using the `@EnableSwagger2` annotation nothing is displayed in Swagger, all I see is a message saying 
`No operations defined in spec!`

Comment: Anyone have any other ideas on how to fix/overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue to my problem. I wasn't aware that Spring Data REST doesn't expose the generated endpoints under the controller package name I had specified here:

`.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.package.name"))`

so when I changed the above line to:

`.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())`

and I could see the JPA respository endpoints.